querying SUPER data type value in REDSHIFT
I have SUPER datatype column in REDSHIFT table "table_1" and column name "column_1" with below value:-
{
"exp_1": "Dynamic-Control",
"exp_2": "Manual",
"exp_3": "DUPLICATE"
}
when I query this table like this:-

SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier to TRUE;
SET enable_case_sensitive_super_attribute to TRUE;

select column_1."exp_3" 
FROM table_1;


It returns result with value in double quotes
"DUPLICATE"

select column_1."exp_3"
FROM table_1;
my question is how to get this value without double quotes and without using type casting, as type casting will be an overhead while querying. so is there any work around? any help would be highly appreciated

Are the double quotes part of the stored value?  Are these being added by your bench?  What is the length of the returned string?

Yes they are part of value , length is variable. Added via json auto from s3 copy command

The TRIM() function can remove a character from the beginning and end of a string.  There's examples at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRIM.html and one is the removing of quotes

No the double quotes in the json he provided are not part of the value of the exp_3 property of the json object.

TRIM() is another option but again will have to apply function on top.  problem is when target column is SUPER and supplied value via JSON AUTO it should only add value and not value with double quotes. That would solve this problem. If you guys can try inserting, using JSON AUTO and confirm its happening with you as well. Then I will have only option to type cast OR use TRIM()

When you represent a string in json you get back “yourstring”. When u query a super u get a super. What you are seeing is the same as select 'DOUBLE'::super so just do select column_1."exp_3"::varchar(max) FROM table_1;

I have already mentioned that it’s part of value. Don’t want to convert data type. That’s  expensive operation.

When you pass json it goes in SUPER column with double quotes where in VARCHAR column it gets added without double quotes.

@alpeshpradhan you aren't understanding... think of SUPER as a binary object, it's not a plain text object, just cause the sql tool you are using displays it as a string doesn't mean its a string.  For example: {"exp_1": "abc", "exp_2": 123}   if you do col.exp_2 you get back 123, not "123", its displaying the internal json representation of the object... but its still json, you have to do col.exp_2::int to actually be able to use it in addition.

dude, don’t know if you tested actual scenario but Just FYI using col.”exp_2” and NOT col.exp_2 as column names may contain special characters . I want to use result set values without quotes and conversation, I posted here to check if there is any other way such as system parameter setting.
